# "sync" Function of glob package not working in Next js

Tags: next.js

I am trying to get list of all files in a directory which end with .md, to do this I used a function "sync" from glob package in next js. But the sync function isn't working as I intend it to, It is supposed to return the file_path to the files which end with .md in given directory, I do have the files but this function is only returning empty list

```
import path from 'path'
import { sync } from 'glob'

const Index=({mdxInDir})=>{

  console.log(mdxInDir)
  //This comes out to be an empty array even when son.md, test.md, why.md files are present in the path specified
  return <></>
}

export default Index

export async function getStaticProps(){

  // 3 files do exist in this directory
  const blogDirPath = path.join(process.cwd(), 'blogData')

  const mdxInDir = sync(`${blogDirPath}/*.md`)

  return {
    props : {
      mdxInDir,
      blogDirPath
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a guess here, but are you using Windows?  Try hard-coding just the local path (e.g., 'blogdata/*.md) and logging the results to the console.  It may be that you're returning something like "blogdata\article.md".